# Proper use of ため to thank someone for doing x？

Tags: grammar, syntax

I know ため can be translated into English as "for" such-and-such.

But is it appropriate to use it to thank some one for doing something?

For example, "Thank you for your email address." Would it be grammatically accurate to say: メールアドレスためありがとうございます。

Google translate seems to understand the sentence perfectly fine. But would a native speaker scratch their head at that use of ため in this manner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using ため as the 'for' in 'thank you for' is strange.

Off the top of my head I can think of 4 ways we normally use ありがとう to say thanks for something.

> 1. masu-stem of the verb + ありがとう (this one's particularly formal)
>      メールアドレスを教えていただき有難う御座います。
>      Thank you for telling me your email address.
> 2. te-form of the verb + ありがとう
>      メールアドレスを教えてくれてありがとう。
>      Thanks for telling me your email address.
> 3. noun + ありがとう
>      メアドありがとう！
>      Thanks for your email address!
> 4. [noun + を + ありがとう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5496/78)
>      メッセージをありがとう
>      Thanks for your message

There's lots of other expressions which don't use ありがとう like:

> ～についてお礼を申し上げます
>   ～に対し感謝します

ため is 'for' as in for the benefit or purpose of someone/something.

> `私のために`こんなすてきなパーティーを開いてくれてありがとう。
>   Thank you for throwing such a splendid party `for me`.

Comment: Reasons 1 and 2 are essentially the same since the 〜て form and 連用形 are pretty interchangeable as connecting clauses.  3 and 4 are basically the same just with(out) the を, and seem to be a form with the verb implied/omitted [as described here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5496/78).  So it's really just like one reason.

Comment: @istrasci It does sometimes help to have the forms entirely expanded out.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie:  Touché

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to understand the usage if you think of `ため` as "for the sake of (smb/smth)".

> 会社{かいしゃ}の**ため**に働{はたら}く
>   Work **in interests** of the company [=for the sake of the company]
>
> 彼女{かのじょ}は娘{むすめ}の**ため**なら何でもやる
>   She will do anything **for** her daughter. [=for the sake of her daughter]
>
> 正義{せいぎ}の**ため**に
>   **In the cause of** justice [=for the sake of justice]

A related meaning is "for the purpose of" or "with the goal of"

> 君{きみ}は何の**ため**にここへ来{き}たのだ。
>   **What** have you come here **for**? [=for what purpose]
>
> 金{かね}の**ため**に働{はたら}く
>   Work **for** the money [= with the goal of getting money]

`ため` may also means "due to" or "because of". It seems to be used this way mostly in formal speech. You can often recognize it by the missing `に` (but this it not a 100% indicator).

> 飛行機{ひこうき}が台風{たいふう}の**ため**欠航{けっこう}した。
>   The flight was canceled **due to** a typhoon.