# How do you say thank you for or sorry for?

Tags: translation

the "for" should be followed by an arbitrarily long and complicated sentence like:

> Thank you for waiting for me after the football match!

or

> Sorry for spilling my drink on the carpet that you got for your birthday.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question exactly but you might find my answer here interesting: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12445/proper-use-of-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81-to-thank-someone-for-doing-x%EF%BC%9F/12446#12446 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the て form.

待ってくれてありがとう。

カーペットを汚してすまない。

Answer (score 5):

Informally, it's usually, ～てくれてありがとう and ～てごめん(なさい).

> サッカー(の[試合]{しあい})の[後]{あと}で待っていてくれてありがとう。
>   [絨毯]{じゅうたん}を[汚]{よご}してごめんなさい。