# だ versus な in causal subordinate clauses

Tags: etymology, classical-japanese, subordinate-clauses, particle-な, old-japanese

Why do causal subordinate clauses ending in -から take だ as a means to connect nouns and な adjectives (e.g. 日本人だから), whereas causal subordinate clauses ending in -ので take な (e.g. 日本人なので)?

I read that だ derives from て+ある, whereas な derives from に+ある, but why would one causal conjunction require で, whereas another one requires に?

Just trying to make sense of it all…

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12097/etymology-of-the-copula-%E3%81%A0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This explanation is tautological but I just have to say it's because から follows a terminal form, which of the copula is だ while の is a kind of noun, which needs an attributive form to be modified, which of the copula is な.

Their etymology has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know why there are two forms though... that's the question.

Comment: @Leebo That's because many verbs originally had two forms, which later got merged into one except the copula.

Comment: That actually kinda clears it up… Thank you!