# だ and です godan or ichidan

Tags: verbs, terminology, godan-verbs, ichidan-verbs

Can we say, that だ and です are godan verbs with ru-ending, because they are just simplyfied versions of である and であります?

Answer (score 3):

According to goo 辞書 dictionary.goo.ne.jp, だ and です are simply 助動詞 or じょどうし。 (helping or auxiliary verb)

I like goo 辞書 for the monolingual definitions.

ある is 動ラ五 meaning 動詞 (どうし)、ラ行　(ぎょう)、五段　(ごだん)。

To me, だ and です are not very verb-like.

It might not be useful to classify them.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I understand that [da]/[desu] are auxiliary verbs, but they must come from something. They can not appear just from nowhere. For example, I have feeling, but I can not prove yet, that だろう [darou] and でしょう [deshyou] are just conjunction of [da]/[desu]. Maybe they all come from だる [daru] as ru-godan? In Jisho.org there is no だる [daru], but may be somewhen in the past だる [daru] was using instead of modern [da]/[desu]?

Comment: @Tchibi-kun “Come from” and “are” are two very different things…

Comment: [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12097/etymology-of-the-copula-%E3%81%A0) question exists, also

Comment: Till now I've found in Jisho.org, that there is archaic verb たり or だり, which are not used anymore in thier [it is X] purpose. But that makes だ not ru-godan, but ri-godan. I guess it is insane idea, cause there are no ri-godans at all. But that would be funny. [I was a kid] instead of contemporary [子供だった] it would turn to [子供だらった].

Comment: @requiredandshown I've read the article you've given. They say interesting idea, that [da] and [na] are the same rooted and both come from [nite-ari] or [te-ari]. Anyway, that makes them definettly not to be ichidans.