# Explanatory particle「の」 comes from 「ので」?

Tags: て-form, particle-の, particle-で

I just saw on Imabi.net :

http://www.imabi.net/karanodenoda.htm

That 「ので」 is actually the て form of the explanatory particle の with だ...

It actually makes a lot of sense if it is true. I`ve always been taught that 「ので」, 「から」 and 「の(だ/です）」 are 3 different things and I used them without actually knowing where they come from.

So if it is true :

> 明日は学校に行かない。風邪を引いたんだ。: Tomorrow I`m not going to school. Because I got a cold.
>
> 風邪を引いたんで、明日は学校に行かない。: Because I got a cold, tomorrow I`m not going to school.

Are　ｔhose two sentences exactly the same and there is no difference in meaning between the 「んだ」 and 「んで」 ?

Thanks a lot!

Edit :

On the dictionary, it is written that 「ので」 comes from the particule の + the 格助詞　で. So if it is the て form of のだ, then the 連用形 of だ is the 格助詞　で？

Comment: Yes. That said, the ので version is just a subordinate clause and less focused.

Comment: Thank you! But if that is so, then the 連用形 of 「だ」 is actually the 格助詞 で ?

Comment: Thanks, but I was talking about : http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/172101/m0u/ this one which is the 「ので」 used in my example sentence in my first post, and it is written that this ので is actually the particle の+で (格助詞), so how can 「ので」 be the て形 of the explanatory の+だ? Knowing that the 連用形 of だ is で also... so is this dictionary wrong?

Comment: I haven't clearly sorted out the relation bteween the particle で and the て form of だ yet but だ comes from である (still used) which comes from にてある (not used anymore). The particle で comes from にて. http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/history-of-%E3%81%A0-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-and-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B/12374#12374
Though the official grammar distinguish between the particle で and the て form of だ, I as a japanese learner (NOT native) consider ので to be the  て form of のだ and the particle で and the て form of だ to be the same thing most of the time (which could be a mistake).

Comment: More on the particle で : http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11357/the-uses-etymology-of-%E3%81%A7

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was thinking. I think people don`t want to make a relation between のだ and ので because of the other usages of のだ for example it`s 命令形 「来るんだ！」 which would be too confusing because we can`t use ので and give an order. Erf this is too confusing

Answer (score 3):

***EDITED for clarity***

One of the main differences between から and ので is as follows:

から is often used when the speaker is indicating subjective impressions. The reason given is the speaker's own judgement, and this means that what follows から is typically some kind of invitation, a warning, an order, etc. For example:
危ないから、走らないで。
The speaker judges that it is dangerous and tells someone not to run.

On the other hand, ので is used when the reason is expressed as an objective fact. For example,
ドルもユーロも値上がりしているので、...

Since this is an objective fact (and not subjective judgement by the speaker), it is more appropriate to use ので.

In general, this distinction can give sentences a different kind of sense and tone. Although your example doesn't relate strictly to that, the use of ので in your example does. 風邪を引いた is presented as an objective fact, thus justifying the use of ので over から. This is different from using the explanatory の at the end of the sentence, which does not have the same effect.

In the second sentence, 引いたんで is ok for informal conversation but not for anything else.

**Summary**

(1) Using the explanatory の at the end of the sentence is different to using ので mid sentence.

(2) Whether to use ので or から depends on whether your are expressing a subjective judgement or an objective fact.

(3) ～んで is only appropriate in a relatively informal situation. Otherwise, use ので.