# Why should I use つかれました and not つかれたです

Tags: grammar, usage, verbs

I said to a Japanese person last night, meaning to say "I'm tired":

> つかれたです。

She corrected me to:

> つかれました。

I'm curious as to why this is. I thought つかれたです was grammatically correct. Does it sound strange or unusual? And why would using the past tense "I felt tired" be preferable to the present tense "I feel tired"?

Please reply in kana or kanji with furigana only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually, です is a polite copula, similar to だ but more polite:

> それはリンゴだ　　That is an apple
>   それはリンゴです　That is an apple (polite)

But です can also be a politeness marker added to adjectives:

> あかい　　　　is red
>   あかいです　　is red (polite)

When it's a politeness marker, です doesn't inflect for tense:

> あかいです　　　　is red (polite)
>   あかかったです　　was red (polite)

The adjective before it already inflects for tense.

This is a relatively recent innovation in the Japanese language and not too long ago was considered unacceptable.  Some people still try to reword things to avoid it, but it's probably caught on because it filled a useful gap in the language: making adjectives polite, like です with nouns or 〜ます with verbs, but without going as far as [〜うございます](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/765/1478).

However, verbs already have a way to make them polite:

> つかれた　　　　(past)
>   つかれました　　(past, polite)

So there's no motivation to start saying *つかれたです, and there's no reason for people to start treating it as an acceptable part of the Japanese language.  As a result, it's ungrammatical.

Comment: I see, so つかれた is a plain past tense verb, not an adjective?

Comment: Yes, it's the past tense of the verb つかれる "be / become tired".

Comment: Ah, わかります。 So つかれたです was grammatical, but now the grammatical method is to inflect the verb and leave out the sentence ending.

Comment: It was never grammatical to add です to verbs.  There was a motivation to add です to adjectives, so over time it became acceptable.  But there was no such motivation for verbs, because verbs already had the 〜ます ending to make them polite.  That is what I tried to explain.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you! +1 and accepted.

Comment: "there's no motivation", motivation or not, people still use it. There are looooads of hits on Google for "疲れたです" by native speakers. "there's no reason for people to start treating it as an acceptable part", what, people using it isn't a good reason? It's not standard, you're right about that, but what you're saying about reasons and motivation doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @dainichi Almost any rule can be broken and I hear つかれたです often enough. I don't like telling people "this is wrong", when it is in fact used by native speakers. In this case, though, I thought that something to the effect of "It's _technically_ wrong, but people use it" would be misleading, considering the OP didn't yet understand the difference between an adjective and a verb and I thought it wise to label つかれたです simply as ungrammatical.

Answer (score 5):

To form the polite past tense, you can't just add です to the non-polite past tense つかれた.

You need to make the polite present tense つかれます into the past tense (i.e. ます -> ました) つかれました.

That the ending ます inflects like any other verb, e.g. (present) はなす -> (past) はなした, is no accident. ます can be thought of as an auxiliary verb.

Comment: I know that つかれまひた is polite past tense. I'm not asking what it is, I'm asking *why* I need to use it. Why can't I simply use the adjective つかれた with present tense sentence ending です?

Comment: Because it's ungrammatical. (BTW, つかれた is **not** an adjective.)

Answer (score 5):

Japanese grammar works in a different way when it comes to forming polite forms of verbs and i-adjectives.

For **verbs**, you add ～ます to the verb and then you form all other verbs forms from combined polite verb:

> つかれる -> つかれます plain -> polite
>
> つかれます -> つかれました polite -> polite past
>
> つかれます -> つかれません polite -> polite negative

It is different for **i-adjectives** though. In that case, you use the plain form of adjectives and just add です.

> おいしい -> おいしいです plain -> polite
>
> おいしかった -> おいしかったです plain past -> polite past
>
> おいしくない -> おいしくないです plain negative -> polite negative

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the grammar right, what might have escaped you is that つかれた is not an adjective like "tired" is in English (ex: He is tired.) . When you realize that it's a past tense of a verb and you have to treat it like 食べる・食べた, everything will make sense to you. You'd say, 食べました but not 食べたです。

To repeat everyone here, 「です」applies only to adjectives. That's why

つかれたです

....is actually gramatically incorrect. And if I may, it's the kind of wrong that really, really sounds wrong so you want to get this right.