# Why is 高いです acceptable but 高いではあります not acceptable?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, copula

[This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/when-is-it-okay-to-use-%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-with-a-living-subject) interesting thread got me thinking about the various forms of the copula and how `です` is a contraction of `で（は）あります`. I am wondering why the standard X は Y で（は）あります does not seem to work for certain words, like i-adjectives.  Please correct me if I am wrong, but I think that the following examples show what I mean:

> **(1)** これは高いです。　**O**
>
> **(2)** これは高いではあります。 **X**
>
> **(3)** 彼は元気です。  **O**
>
> **(4)** 彼は元気ではあります。**O**

**(2)** is the only one that feels unnatural to me but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because an i-adjective does not require だ (or its te-form で) in the first place. です at the end of a sentence like これは高いです is **not a copula** but a politeness marker which never conjugates.

- [Why should I use つかれました and not つかれたです](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15300/5010):

  > Usually, です is a polite copula, similar to だ but more polite. But です can also be a politeness marker added to adjectives. When it's a politeness marker, です doesn't inflect for tense.
- [です after some verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/35950/5010)

  > In Japanese, there's no need for a verb like be to show tense on adjectives. Adjectives can indicate tense all on their own, using the endings -い and -かった. In this case, です doesn't have its usual grammatical function. Instead, it's functioning as a politeness marker.

Instead, you can say これは高くはあります without using だ/で at all.

Comment: あっ！「The です in #3 in a copula, but the です in #1 is a politeness marker rather than a copula. You can see this from the fact that you say これは高い, but not これは高いだ」まで書いたところだったｗｗ　またおんなじになるとこやったかもｗｗ

Comment: @naruto How about if I add ん to 高い？これは高いんです。Is this still a politeness marker or does the ん・の introduce a copula? And how would you add the ん to 高くはあります?

Comment: @kandyman That の/ん is a formal noun, so it takes a normal copula that conjugates (e.g. 高いんでした). And 高くはあります + ん = 高くはあるんです.

Comment: I see. By the way, if これは高い doesn't need a copula or a verb, how can we categorize this as a sentence? It isn't a verbal phrase nor a noun phrase. How is are these structures analyzed in Japanese linguistics?

Comment: @kandyman That's exactly why some linguists say [Japanese i-adjectives are actually verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1016/5010). In Japanese 国語文法, i-adjectives and verbs are both categorized as 用言, and they share almost the same set of conjugation types (連用形, 連体形, 未然形, etc).

Comment: @kandyman, various languages have a part of speech described in English as a [stative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb).  Some analyses of Japanese treat ～い adjectives as stative verbs, since ～い adjectives can be used as predicates.

Answer (score 2):

#### Addendum: derivations and grammar

Adding onto naruto's answer.

One additional way of looking at this that might help explain why で[は]あります cannot be used with ～い adjectives, is that で (not だ nor です) evolved from earlier にて.  This is a hint -- the に is essentially the same as the adverbial に added to な adjectives.  Examples:

- 元気な `[NOUN]`
- 元気に `[VERB]`
- 元気だ (where the だ is the copula "is")
- 元気です (where the です serves as *both* the copula "is", and as a politeness marker)
- 元気‍**で**ある → older form 元気‍**にて**‍ある

The corresponding grammatical structures for an ～い adjective:

- 高い `[NOUN]`
- 高く `[VERB]`
- 高い (where the ～い adjective all on its own already forms a complete predicate -- we don't need a copula.  Saying 高い‍**だ** is a bit like saying "it is **is** tall".)
- 高いです (where the です serves *just* as a politeness marker)
- 高‍**く**‍ある
  The く here aligns with the に particle in the older form にてある for ～な adjectives.

To modify ある, both ～い and ～な adjectives must be in the adverbial form, although this is obscured by the contraction にて → で.

(As for why ～な adjectives also require the connecting auxiliary ～て before ある, whereas ～い adjectives do not [*高く‍**て**‍ある is incorrect], I haven't found any cogent explanation, so if anyone can add that, I'd be most grateful.)

Comment: So what was the old form for i-adjectives? If 元気にてある was the old form for na-adjectives but there was no 高くてある then when was actually used?

Comment: The にてある for な adjectives matches the くある form for い adjectives, as I tried to show using the parallel bulleted lists.  Was that unclear?  Should I edit to clarify?  Historically, this construction stretches back to Old Japanese ～くあり, equating to modern (though archaic / formal) ～くある.  See [various instances in the _Man'yōshū_](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/%20%22%E3%81%8F%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%22), for instance.

Comment: You mean that にてある became である and that くあり became くある? Is that correct?

Comment: A similar search reveals that [にてあり was not used](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/%20%22%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A6%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%22).  However, the 形容動詞 (in modern Japanese, the ～な adjective) [didn't really exist in the language until the Heian Period](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E#%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81), some time after the _Man'yōshū_ was written.

Comment: @kandyman, yes, にてあり in classical and older Japanese becomes modern である, while くあり in classical and older becomes modern くある.