# what is the function of "口惜しゅうて" in below sentence?

Tags: grammar

I searched for the word "口惜しゅうて" on the internet but I found "口惜しい".
I want to know how "口惜しい" changes to "口惜しゅうて" in the below sentence:
"おぬしの生きざま,**口惜しゅうて**仕方ないわ!"

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42890/45489

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the [Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF#%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E8%A9%9E%E3%81%AE%E9%80%A3%E7%94%A8%E5%BD%A2) on 音便{おんびん} (euphonic change). This is a historical sound change which is simply equivalent to what would be spelled 口惜{くや}しくて.

Comment: Thank you very much.