# Meaning of からはよ in this sentence

Tags: translation, particles, colloquial-language

A character is trying to cross a checkpoint, but an official is asking for a pass.
The character answers:

```
知らん！ 急いでるからはよ通せ。
```

Using this [this StackExchange question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30995/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8F-%E2%86%92-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8F-in-other-contexts-similar-2-kana-to-1-kana-shortcuts) I came up with this translation:

"I don't understand! We are in a hurry **????** let us through".

In my understanding, 知らん is short/rough for 知らんない, and 急いでる is 急いで + いる (shortened). 通せ is the "command form" of 通す. The leaves からはよ, that I cannot understand.

Is my translation correct and what does mean **からはよ** here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

はよ is a dialectal from of はやく (preserved in the standard language somewhat in お早う{おはよう}). The progression went はやく -> はやう -> はよう -> はよ. You'll see this kind of thing with other i-adjectives too, like よろしゅお願いします or よう聞け.

> 知らん！急いでるからはよ通せ。

=

> 知らない！急いでいるから早く通せ。

> I don't care! We're in a hurry, so let us through already.

(I say dialectal, but sometimes this is also role language for old men)

Comment: Thank you! What's the name of this dialect?

Comment: @ash I think a fair few dialects do it, but it's primarily associated with Kansai.

Comment: @ash This was "standard" in classical Japanese. See these questions: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42890/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24217/5010

Comment: @AeonAkechi Found it! http://www.kansaiben.com/1.Characteristics/2.LinguisticAspects/d-Conjugation.html has a whole table for this example, which I'm very happy about. Thank you so much! BTW, I've never thought that  おはよう is related to 早い, though in hindsight it should have been obvious.

Comment: @naruto Thank you for the links. Honestly, _understanding_ this is probably beyond my level right now, but it is very useful to know.